# "+" character in the js echoed edited data from html page is replaced with empty space in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am building an webpage that has editable data fields linked with MySql database.

```
<th>CONTACT 1 NUMBER*</th>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" contenteditable="true" data-old_value="<?php echo $rows["emr1_number"]; ?>"  onBlur="saveInlineEdit(this,'emr1_number','<?php echo $rows["safr_id"]; ?>','<?php echo $userRow['userId']; ?>')"><?php echo $rows["emr1_number"]; ?></td>
```

The above code is used in html side to show data and get new data if the fields are edited.

```
function saveInlineEdit1(editableObj,column,id,uid) {
    // no change change made then return false
    if($(editableObj).attr('data-old_value') === editableObj.innerHTML)
    return false;
    // send ajax to update value
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loader.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
        url: "saveInlineEdit1.php",
        cache: false,
        data:'column='+column+'&value='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id+'&uid='+uid,
        success: function(response)  {
            console.log(response);
            // set updated value as old value
            $(editableObj).attr('data-old_value',editableObj.innerHTML);
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");         
        }          
   });
}
```

Above JS is used to get edited data and make an AJAX call.

this is saveInlineEdit1.php

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");
$sql = "UPDATE coin_location set ".$_REQUEST["column"]."='".$_REQUEST["value"]."' WHERE  coin_id='".$_REQUEST["id"]."' AND userId='".$_REQUEST["uid"]."'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
echo "saved";
?>
```

Everything is working fine. Only problem I have is, If am editing the data field with "+" sign, For ex, changing the data "hello" with "+hello" in webpage. Actually the data altered in database must be "+hello" but i get " hello". An empty space is replaced in the place of "+" sign.

Please, help me to get rid of this.

Thanks.

Comment: The data retrieved from database is "hello" and it is displayed in the webpage. The User of the webpage changes "hello" to "+hello". But in the database "+hello" is stores as " hello"

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript, here '+' is used for appending, but I want the character '+' from editable html table cell to be stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is (correctly) treating a + in a GET parameter as a space. You need to encode your value as url before sending it, e.g. with [encodeURIComponent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp). Then on the server side you can use urldecode to get the original value.

**Edit after comment:**

So in your JavaScript you would do something like

```
data:'column='+column+'&value='+encodeURIComponent(editableObj.innerHTML)+'&id='+id+'&uid='+uid,`
```

And in PHP:

```
$sql = "UPDATE coin_location set ".$_REQUEST["column"]."='".urldecode($_REQUEST["value"])."' WHERE  coin_id='".$_REQUEST["id"]."' AND userId='".$_REQUEST["uid"]."'";
```

**IMPORTANT WARNING:** That code shows how to solve your current issue, but you should NEVER insert unchecked user input into SQL like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, Is there any other possible approach for this problem, or only this URL way. I don't know how the URL method is applicable for the application architecture I have built.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. You don't need to change anything, just encode and decode the value. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I tried it, but same problem prevails. I tried both GET and POST. i think something like this is to used separately, and then appended into ajax url, `var encoded = encodeURIComponent(str);` . Isn't both same ?

Comment: Am getting "object Object" get stored in the database while trying encode and decode as you said.

Comment: edited the code, now am not getting "object Object". But still "+" sign is replaced with empty space.

Answer (score 0):

As @GertG suggested URL Encode Decode is the way.

in Javascript,

```
data:'column='+column+'&value='+encodeURIComponent(editableObj.innerHTML)+'&id='+id+'&uid='+uid,
```

in PHP,

```
$sql = "UPDATE coin_location set ".$_REQUEST["column"]."='".rawurldecode($_REQUEST["value"])."' WHERE  coin_id='".$_REQUEST["id"]."' AND userId='".$_REQUEST["uid"]."'";
```

Using `rawurldecode($str)` instead `urldecode($str)` solves the problem !